# SSIS Derived Column (Find String)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am extracting pattern from the 'Notes' column, I am looking for an alpha numeric word (MXPC123456) from the notes and I want to store the output in a new column. So for that I am using a `Derived Column` and `FindString()` function.

I am getting error when I run this code using the following expression in `Drived Column` inside my `SSIS` package:

```
(DT_WSTR,255)SUBSTRING(TEXT_LINE1,FINDSTRING(TEXT_LINE1,"MXPC",1),10).
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong.

> Error: 0xC0049067 at Get DC Coms Data, Derived Column [67]: An error occurred while evaluating the function.
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at Get DC Coms Data, Derived Column [67]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column" (67)" failed because error code 0xC0049067 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "CKT_MX" (91)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Get DC Coms Data, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Derived Column" (67) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Derived Column Input" (68). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Could you please help?

Regards
Prab

Comment: Please supply ALL the properties of the component in question so someone can help you further. For example this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362998/ssis-derived-column

Comment: Presumably the string length you are checking is less than the found string + 10 characters?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that may cause this error:

1. `TEXT_LINE1` doesn't contains `"MXPC"` string , so  `FINDSTRING(TEXT_LINE1,"MXPC",1)` will return `0` and the `SUBSTRING` function will throw an exception
2. `TEXT_LINE1` contains `"MXPC"` string but there is no 10 characters after the `FINDSTRING` returned value
3. `TEXT_LINE1` IS NULL

so you can add some validation to this expression

```
 ISNULL([TEXT_LINE1]) == TRUE ? "" : (FINDSTRING([TEXT_LINE1],"MXPC",1) == 0    ?  "" :  
 (LEN([TEXT_LINE1])  >= FINDSTRING([TEXT_LINE1],"MXPC",1) + 9  ?   SUBSTRING([TEXT_LINE1],FINDSTRING([TEXT_LINE1],"MXPC",1),10)  : ""))
```

Comment: Also it may fails if `[TEXT_LINE1]` is NULL, so you have to add a validation for that.

Comment: Thanks, i will try and let you know

Comment: @PrabhakerKannan i edited the expression to check if the column is NULL